# Add a data frame calculated column on filtered element

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add a calculated column to a data frame to find CpK on each series of group / Component (group1 /R1, group1 / R2 ...), data frame is like :

```
Table1 :
! Group ! Component ! Data ! High_Limit ! LOW_LIMIT !
!-------!-----------!------!------------!-----------!
!group1 ! R1        ! 10   !  12        !  8        !
!group1 ! R1        ! 11   !  12        !  8        !
!group1 ! R2        ! 50   !  60        !  45       !
!group1 ! R2        ! 55   !  60        !  45       !
!group2 ! C1        ! 9    !  12        !  8.5      !
!group2 ! C1        ! 10.5 !  12        !  9        !
!group2 ! R3        ! 11.5 !  12        !  9        !
!group2 ! R3        ! 9.5  !  12        !  9        !
and so on ...
```

Calcul for Cpk is :

```
m <- mean(table1$Data)
s <- sd(table1$Data)

Ts <- max(table1$HIGH_LIMIT)
Ti <- min(table1$LOW_LIMIT) 

CpK <- min((m-Ti)/(3*s), (Ts-m)/(3*s))
```

Could you please help me ?

Here the real data frame exported (on samples)

```
"UUT_NAME"  "STATION_NUM"   "START_DATE_TIME"   "LOW_LIMIT" "DATA"  "HIGH_LIMIT"    "UNITS" "STEP_NAME"
```

"32"    "CELOGIC.MA-6475"   "00 00297"  2014-01-27 16:30:38 88  103.83455   112 "pF"    "C10"
"104"   "CELOGIC.MA-6475"   "00 00297"  2014-01-27 16:30:38 87.9    89.64711    93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"105"   "CELOGIC.MA-6475"   "00 00297"  2014-01-27 16:30:38 2.08    2.13345 2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"106"   "CELOGIC.MA-6475"   "00 00297"  2014-01-27 16:30:38 29.1    30.057545   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"107"   "CELOGIC.MA-6475"   "00 00297"  2014-01-27 16:30:38 29.1    30.086464   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"1005"  "CELOGIC.MA-2161"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 13:58:38 88  104.37667   112 "pF"    "C10"
"1077"  "CELOGIC.MA-2161"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 13:58:38 87.9    89.788269   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"1078"  "CELOGIC.MA-2161"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 13:58:38 2.08    2.13431 2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"1079"  "CELOGIC.MA-2161"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 13:58:38 29.1    30.045176   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"1080"  "CELOGIC.MA-2161"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 13:58:38 29.1    30.049561   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"1978"  "CELOGIC.MA-2161"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 14:09:17 88  104.7235    112 "pF"    "C10"
"2050"  "CELOGIC.MA-2161"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 14:09:17 87.9    89.813126   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"2051"  "CELOGIC.MA-2161"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 14:09:17 2.08    2.134059    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"2052"  "CELOGIC.MA-2161"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 14:09:17 29.1    30.048182   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"2053"  "CELOGIC.MA-2161"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 14:09:17 29.1    30.056608   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"2951"  "CELOGIC.MA-4329"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 14:30:51 88  104.03241   112 "pF"    "C10"
"3023"  "CELOGIC.MA-4329"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 14:31:38 88  103.96976   112 "pF"    "C10"
"3095"  "CELOGIC.MA-4329"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 14:31:38 87.9    89.63073    93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"3096"  "CELOGIC.MA-4329"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 14:31:38 2.08    2.141897    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"3097"  "CELOGIC.MA-4329"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 14:31:38 29.1    30.035461   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"3098"  "CELOGIC.MA-4329"   "00 00362"  2014-05-13 14:31:38 29.1    30.104946   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"3996"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:30:36 88  104.51376   112 "pF"    "C10"
"4068"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:30:36 87.9    90.733009   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"4069"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:30:36 2.08    2.141215    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"4070"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:30:36 29.1    30.147131   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"4071"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:30:36 29.1    30.113092   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"4892"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:39:36 88  107.34245   112 "pF"    "C10"
"4964"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:39:36 87.9    90.934967   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"4965"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:39:36 2.08    2.140769    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"4966"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:39:36 29.1    30.136806   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"4967"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:39:36 29.1    30.114983   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"5534"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:42:13 88  105.98895   112 "pF"    "C10"
"5606"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:42:13 87.9    90.628517   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"5607"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:42:13 2.08    2.141326    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"5608"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:42:13 29.1    30.142355   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"5609"  "CELOGIC.MA-2374"   "00 00297"  2014-06-19 14:42:13 29.1    30.122778   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"6507"  "CELOGIC.MA-2454"   "00 00297"  2014-09-05 09:26:10 88  103.49479   112 "pF"    "C10"
"6579"  "CELOGIC.MA-2454"   "00 00297"  2014-09-05 09:26:10 87.9    90.358688   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"6580"  "CELOGIC.MA-2454"   "00 00297"  2014-09-05 09:26:10 2.08    2.141122    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"6581"  "CELOGIC.MA-2454"   "00 00297"  2014-09-05 09:26:10 29.1    30.058239   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"6582"  "CELOGIC.MA-2454"   "00 00297"  2014-09-05 09:26:10 29.1    30.06591    31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"7430"  "CELOGIC.MA-2454"   "00 00297"  2014-09-05 09:35:27 88  103.60199   112 "pF"    "C10"
"7502"  "CELOGIC.MA-2454"   "00 00297"  2014-09-05 09:35:27 87.9    90.354286   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"7503"  "CELOGIC.MA-2454"   "00 00297"  2014-09-05 09:35:27 2.08    2.142168    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"7504"  "CELOGIC.MA-2454"   "00 00297"  2014-09-05 09:35:27 29.1    30.063662   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"7505"  "CELOGIC.MA-2454"   "00 00297"  2014-09-05 09:35:27 29.1    30.070904   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"8414"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00366"  2015-03-06 07:50:56 88  102.51865   112 "pF"    "C10"
"8486"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00366"  2015-03-06 07:50:56 87.9    90.974564   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"8487"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00366"  2015-03-06 07:50:56 2.08    2.148871    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"8488"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00366"  2015-03-06 07:50:56 29.1    29.983458   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"8489"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00366"  2015-03-06 07:50:56 29.1    30.128607   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"8918"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00366"  2015-03-06 07:59:56 88  103.016 112 "pF"    "C10"
"8990"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00366"  2015-03-06 07:59:56 87.9    90.883461   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"8991"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00366"  2015-03-06 07:59:56 2.08    2.148184    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"8992"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00366"  2015-03-06 07:59:56 29.1    29.975309   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"8993"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00366"  2015-03-06 07:59:56 29.1    30.137098   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"9426"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 13:52:21 88  102.54838   112 "pF"    "C10"
"9498"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 13:52:21 87.9    89.871902   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"9499"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 13:52:21 2.08    2.142678    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"9500"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 13:52:21 29.1    29.947052   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"9501"  "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 13:52:21 29.1    30.094099   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"10399" "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 14:36:44 88  102.50674   112 "pF"    "C10"
"10471" "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 14:36:44 87.9    89.974739   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"10472" "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 14:36:44 2.08    2.142947    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"10473" "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 14:36:44 29.1    29.953632   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"10474" "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 14:36:44 29.1    30.089359   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"10903" "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 14:50:37 88  102.88899   112 "pF"    "C10"
"10975" "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 14:50:37 87.9    90.077881   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"10976" "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 14:50:37 2.08    2.142447    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"10977" "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 14:50:37 29.1    29.951406   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"10978" "CELOGIC.MA-1610"   "00 00362"  2015-03-09 14:50:37 29.1    30.092203   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"11876" "CELOGIC.MA-0887"   "00 00362"  2015-03-17 14:19:37 88  105.72658   112 "pF"    "C10"
"11948" "CELOGIC.MA-0887"   "00 00362"  2015-03-17 14:19:37 87.9    89.542099   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"11949" "CELOGIC.MA-0887"   "00 00362"  2015-03-17 14:19:37 2.08    2.143392    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"11950" "CELOGIC.MA-0887"   "00 00362"  2015-03-17 14:19:37 29.1    29.941921   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"11951" "CELOGIC.MA-0887"   "00 00362"  2015-03-17 14:19:37 29.1    29.980062   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"12849" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:47:55 88  104.56109   112 "pF"    "C10"
"12921" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:47:55 87.9    90.826813   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"12922" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:47:55 2.08    2.13772 2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"12923" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:47:55 29.1    29.979958   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"12924" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:47:55 29.1    30.028364   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"13445" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:49:22 88  104.10088   112 "pF"    "C10"
"13517" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:49:22 87.9    90.849869   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"13518" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:49:22 2.08    2.136499    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"13519" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:49:22 29.1    29.981756   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"13520" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:49:22 29.1    30.028885   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"13748" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:49:49 88  105.10763   112 "pF"    "C10"
"13820" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:49:49 87.9    90.826553   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"13821" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:49:49 2.08    2.137116    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"13822" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:49:49 29.1    29.984587   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"13823" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 14:49:49 29.1    30.029911   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"14721" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 15:03:52 88  104.18301   112 "pF"    "C10"
"14793" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 15:03:52 87.9    90.603035   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"14794" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 15:03:52 2.08    2.136766    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"14795" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 15:03:52 29.1    29.987928   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"14796" "CELOGIC.MA-2189"   "00 00399"  2015-10-30 15:03:52 29.1    30.042906   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"15694" "CELOGIC.MA-2316"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 14:52:56 88  103.85734   112 "pF"    "C10"
"15766" "CELOGIC.MA-2316"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 14:52:56 87.9    90.941826   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"15767" "CELOGIC.MA-2316"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 14:52:56 2.08    2.135956    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"15768" "CELOGIC.MA-2316"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 14:52:56 29.1    29.919226   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"15769" "CELOGIC.MA-2316"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 14:52:56 29.1    30.054958   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"16667" "CELOGIC.MA-0906"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 15:30:48 88  106.41589   112 "pF"    "C10"
"16739" "CELOGIC.MA-0906"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 15:30:48 87.9    90.797607   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"16740" "CELOGIC.MA-0906"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 15:30:48 2.08    2.134154    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"16741" "CELOGIC.MA-0906"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 15:30:48 29.1    30.109236   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"16742" "CELOGIC.MA-0906"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 15:30:48 29.1    30.025709   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"17640" "CELOGIC.MA-0906"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 15:52:41 88  106.77251   112 "pF"    "C10"
"17712" "CELOGIC.MA-0906"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 15:52:41 87.9    90.557838   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"17713" "CELOGIC.MA-0906"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 15:52:41 2.08    2.132611    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"17714" "CELOGIC.MA-0906"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 15:52:41 29.1    30.115213   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"17715" "CELOGIC.MA-0906"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 15:52:41 29.1    30.049799   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"18144" "CELOGIC.MA-3154"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 16:12:23 88  104.15064   112 "pF"    "C10"
"18216" "CELOGIC.MA-3154"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 16:12:23 87.9    90.598541   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"18217" "CELOGIC.MA-3154"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 16:12:23 2.08    2.136247    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"18218" "CELOGIC.MA-3154"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 16:12:23 29.1    30.099293   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"18219" "CELOGIC.MA-3154"   "00 00399"  2015-11-02 16:12:23 29.1    29.956236   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"18787" "CELOGIC.MA-3154"   "00 00399"  2015-11-03 09:20:08 88  104.50943   112 "pF"    "C10"
"18859" "CELOGIC.MA-3154"   "00 00399"  2015-11-03 09:20:08 87.9    90.196915   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"18860" "CELOGIC.MA-3154"   "00 00399"  2015-11-03 09:20:08 2.08    2.136503    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"18861" "CELOGIC.MA-3154"   "00 00399"  2015-11-03 09:20:08 29.1    30.089535   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"18862" "CELOGIC.MA-3154"   "00 00399"  2015-11-03 09:20:08 29.1    29.956837   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"19760" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00362"  2016-03-09 16:12:04 88  104.67191   112 "pF"    "C10"
"19832" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00362"  2016-03-09 16:12:04 87.9    90.35878    93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"19833" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00362"  2016-03-09 16:12:04 2.08    2.145689    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"19834" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00362"  2016-03-09 16:12:04 29.1    30.158304   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"19835" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00362"  2016-03-09 16:12:04 29.1    30.004744   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"20264" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00399"  2016-03-09 14:14:01 88  103.27634   112 "pF"    "C10"
"20336" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00399"  2016-03-09 14:14:01 87.9    90.543076   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"20337" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00399"  2016-03-09 14:14:01 2.08    2.144124    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"20338" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00399"  2016-03-09 14:14:01 29.1    30.138008   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"20339" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00399"  2016-03-09 14:14:01 29.1    29.987755   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"21237" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00399"  2016-03-09 16:02:18 88  103.43541   112 "pF"    "C10"
"21309" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00399"  2016-03-09 16:02:18 87.9    90.312469   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"21310" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00399"  2016-03-09 16:02:18 2.08    2.145076    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"21311" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00399"  2016-03-09 16:02:18 29.1    30.144836   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"21312" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00399"  2016-03-09 16:02:18 29.1    29.99951    31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"22210" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00362"  2016-03-10 09:07:24 88  103.84418   112 "pF"    "C10"
"22282" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00362"  2016-03-10 09:07:24 87.9    90.39769    93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"22283" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00362"  2016-03-10 09:07:24 2.08    2.145807    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"22284" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00362"  2016-03-10 09:07:24 29.1    30.145554   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"22285" "CELOGIC.MA-2610"   "00 00362"  2016-03-10 09:07:24 29.1    29.995651   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"23183" "CELOGIC.MA-2609"   "00 00399"  2016-06-02 09:45:43 88  103.39602   112 "pF"    "C10"
"23255" "CELOGIC.MA-2609"   "00 00399"  2016-06-02 09:45:43 87.9    90.332397   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"23256" "CELOGIC.MA-2609"   "00 00399"  2016-06-02 09:45:43 2.08    2.146439    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"23257" "CELOGIC.MA-2609"   "00 00399"  2016-06-02 09:45:43 29.1    30.082825   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"23258" "CELOGIC.MA-2609"   "00 00399"  2016-06-02 09:45:43 29.1    30.07023    31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"24156" "CELOGIC.MA-2609"   "00 00399"  2016-06-02 10:35:59 88  103.07425   112 "pF"    "C10"
"24228" "CELOGIC.MA-2609"   "00 00399"  2016-06-02 10:35:59 87.9    90.374924   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"24229" "CELOGIC.MA-2609"   "00 00399"  2016-06-02 10:35:59 2.08    2.145505    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"24230" "CELOGIC.MA-2609"   "00 00399"  2016-06-02 10:35:59 29.1    30.075659   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"24231" "CELOGIC.MA-2609"   "00 00399"  2016-06-02 10:35:59 29.1    30.067387   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"25128" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-22 15:43:27 88  102.41218   112 "pF"    "C10"
"25200" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-22 15:43:27 87.9    89.970772   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"25201" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-22 15:43:27 2.08    2.135011    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"25202" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-22 15:43:27 29.1    30.171347   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"25203" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-22 15:43:27 29.1    30.038151   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"26101" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 08:52:49 88  102.64326   112 "pF"    "C10"
"26173" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 08:52:49 87.9    90.041145   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"26174" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 08:52:49 2.08    2.13542 2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"26175" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 08:52:49 29.1    30.17922    31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"26176" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 08:52:49 29.1    30.034796   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"26605" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 09:48:51 88  102.55943   112 "pF"    "C10"
"26677" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 09:48:51 87.9    89.94989    93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"26678" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 09:48:51 2.08    2.136524    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"26679" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 09:48:51 29.1    30.172457   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"26680" "CELOGIC.MA-102"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 09:48:51 29.1    30.039785   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"27578" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 10:31:02 88  106.16189   112 "pF"    "C10"
"27650" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 10:31:02 87.9    90.254478   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"27651" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 10:31:02 2.08    2.143642    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"27652" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 10:31:02 29.1    30.03858    31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"27653" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 10:31:02 29.1    30.034452   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"28082" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 11:22:45 88  105.13081   112 "pF"    "C10"
"28154" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 11:22:45 87.9    90.153961   93.9    "KO"    "R1"
"28155" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 11:22:45 2.08    2.143321    2.22    "KO"    "R2"
"28156" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 11:22:45 29.1    30.020109   31.1    "KO"    "R3"
"28157" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00323"  2016-07-25 11:22:45 29.1    30.049246   31.1    "KO"    "R4"
"29055" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00362"  2016-07-25 13:25:13 88  106.46228   112 "pF"    "C10"
"29127" "CELOGIC.MA-100"    "00 00362"  2016-07-25 13:25:13 87.9    90.300667   93.9    "KO"    "R1"

Comment: You are not going to get any help if you dont provide a better example of your data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`

```
table1 <- read.table(text = " Group  Component  Data  High_Limit  LOW_LIMIT 
                 group1  R1         10     12          8        
                 group1  R1         11     12          8        
                 group1  R2         50     60          45       
                 group1  R2         55     60          45       
                 group2  C1         9      12          8.5      
                 group2  C1         10.5   12          9        
                 group2  R3         11.5   12          9        
                 group2  R3         9.5    12          9", header = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
table2 <- table1 %>%
  group_by(Group, Component) %>%
  summarise(m = mean(Data), s = sd(Data), Ts = max(High_Limit),
            Ts = max(High_Limit), Ti = min(LOW_LIMIT)) %>%
  mutate(CpK = min((m-Ti)/(3*s), (Ts-m)/(3*s)))
# final data frame
table3 <- left_join(table1, table2, by = c("Group", "Component"))
```

Comment: CpK values return me  "NaN", I don't understand why, I guess it's the min function,  If I add na.rm = TRUE results are "-Inf" -  I tried with  mutate(Cp = ((Ts-Ti)/(6*s))..  - Values are good - Any ideas about that ?

Comment: Of course, it could be a consequence of the presence of `NA` values in your data (it's actually difficult to find the reason without seeing your data). However, you might note that if `s` is `NaN` or `0`, the denominator when computing `CpK` would be `NaN` or `Inf`. Try `1/NaN` and `1/0` and see the results.

Comment: Ok I mean the values of CpK is constant and I think I find why : My dataframe include some négatives Date with Ti negative and Ts positive - How can I filtered a column by a partial string - I mean for example if a component is "SHORT1" or "SHORTn" I could suppress the row including it -  Like table1 <- table1[!(table1$Component == "CONTINUITIES" | table1$Component== "SHORTS"),] Thank you

Comment: I tried : test <- (min((cpk_total$m-cpk_total$Ti)/(3*cpk_total$s), (cpk_total$Ts-cpk_total$m)/(3*cpk_total$s))) where cpk_total is my dataframe with correct columns m, s , Ti and Ts calculated and result is a constant value - If I try (cpk_total$Ts-cpk_total$m)/(3*cpk_total$s)) it's correct too like function min doesn't work with the data frame

Comment: Is there a solution to apply the min funtion on a data frame ?

Comment: I just exported in txt format a sample of my data frame - Component are named STEP_NAME - I wish add a column with the calculated CpK like see before - Hope it will be Ok for understanding my problem - thank you